# How i can do this with functional programming?

Tags: javascript, redux, functional-programming, redux-saga

In relation to functional programming, when I'm going to do an remove of a serie using a sagas, is it correct to generate a new object for the action.serie, even if you do not go to alter the manipulated object?

```
export function* removeSerie(action){
try{
    const user = yield new Promise(resolve => {
        const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            resolve(user)
            unsub()
          }
        })
    })
    const url = `users/${user.id}/series/${actio.serie.genre}/${action.serie.id}`
    yield database.ref(url).remove()
    yield put(ActionCreator.removeSerieSuccess(action.serie.id))
    yield getSeries(action.serie.genre)
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.removeSerieFailure(message))
}  
}
               or

export function* removeSerie(action){
const serie = {...action.serie}  //action.serie is the serie passed for remove, with id, name, genre...
try{
    const user = yield new Promise(resolve => {
        const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            resolve(user)
            unsub()
          }
        })
    })
    const idUser = user.uid  //is necessary do this?
    const url = `users/${idUser}/series/${serie.genre}/${serie.id}`
    yield database.ref(url).remove()
    yield put(ActionCreator.removeSerieSuccess(serie.id))
    yield getSeries(serie.genre)
}catch({message}){
    yield put(ActionCreator.removeSerieFailure(message))
}  
}
```

How option is better to use?

Comment: FP states that state is immutable. If you're not applying any changes to the object then there's no sense to return copy of the object. It's a waste of the CPU. Just return an unchanged object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about data immutability in functional programming, you don't have to create a shallow copied object for your example assuming `removeSerieSuccess` `getSeries` etc should be pure(or at least not mutating `serie` that get passed).

And when you see sometimes people make shallow copied before passing to other function like in redux reducer because it's easier to detect changes in which you can just check by reference that's incredibly useful in `react-redux` which use aggressive `shouldComponentUpdate`to avoid unnecessary rerender. But redux in fact actually doesn't' **require** the reducer to be pure but it's encouraged to have better predictability.